# What's wrong in this expansion of this erfc-like function?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, power-series, error-function

Given the function $$H(x)=\int_{-x}^{+\infty}dy \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$, I would like to write it as a series expansion employing integration by parts:
$$\int_{-x}^{+\infty}dy \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=y\frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\vert_{-x}^{+\infty}+\int_{-x}^{+\infty}dy y^2 \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+...+\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!!}+...\right)$$.
The problem is evident: in $x=0$ the expansion doesn't seem to be equal to $1/2$ as it should. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's because the remainder term of the form $\int_{-x}^{\infty}{y^{2k}\frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dy}$ can't just be thrown away like you've done, even when it's divided by $(2k+1)!!$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly you did integration by parts correctly (which was useless here) but you cant use series because of infinity.

So you need just to use partition of an interval
$$ H(x)=\int_{-x}^{\infty} \frac{e{-\frac{y^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dy=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dy+\int_{-x}^{0} \frac{e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dy$$
then for the first integral its Gaussian integral which give us
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dy=\frac{1}{2}$$
also for the second
$$\int_{-x}^{0} \frac{e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dy=\int_{-x}^{0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{-y^2}{2}\right)^ndy=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{-(-x)^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n$$
using the series form for the error function and get
$$ H(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n+1)}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2n+1}$$
finally
$$ H(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left( \text{erf} \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+1 \right) $$